Singular matrix during B Spline interpolation
According to the literature about B Splines, including Wolfram Mathworld, the condition for Cox de Boor's recursive function states that:

In python, this would translate to:
if (d_ == 0):
   if ( knots_[k_] <= t_ < knots_[k_+1]):
      return 1.0
   return 0.0

where:

d_: degree of the curve
knots_: knot vector
k_: index of the knot
t_: parameter value {0.0,...,1.0} (reparametrized)

However, this seems to generate a Singular matrix, when creating the linear system intended for interpolation, not approximation. For example, with 4 points:
  A = [[1.         0.         0.         0.        ]
       [0.2962963  0.44444444 0.22222222 0.03703704]
       [0.03703704 0.22222222 0.44444444 0.2962963 ]
       [0.         0.         0.         **0.**    ]] //The last element (bottom-right) should have been 1.0
  # Error: LinAlgError: file C:\Users\comevo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numpy\linalg\_linalg.py line 104: Singular matrix

If I change the second part of the condition to:
if (d_ == 0):
   if ( knots_[k_] <= t_ <= knots_[k_+1]): // using <= instead of <
      return 1.0
   return 0.0

I get the correct matrix and the correct spline.
A = [[1.         0.         0.         0.        ]
     [0.2962963  0.44444444 0.22222222 0.03703704]
     [0.03703704 0.22222222 0.44444444 0.2962963 ]
     [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]] // OK

Why does the code need to deviate from the mathematical condition in order to get the correct results and the iterator reaching the last element?
See below the complete example code:
import numpy as np
import math
from geomdl import knotvector

def cox_de_boor( d_, t_, k_, knots_):
    if (d_ == 0):
        if ( knots_[k_] <= t_ <= knots_[k_+1]):
            return 1.0
        return 0.0
    
    denom_l = (knots_[k_+d_] - knots_[k_])
    left = 0.0    
    if (denom_l != 0.0):
        left = ((t_ - knots_[k_]) / denom_l) * cox_de_boor(d_-1, t_, k_, knots_)
    
    denom_r = (knots_[k_+d_+1] - knots_[k_+1])
    right = 0.0
    if (denom_r != 0.0):
        right = ((knots_[k_+d_+1] - t_) / denom_r) * cox_de_boor(d_-1, t_, k_+1, knots_)

    return left + right

def interpolate( d_, P_, n_, ts_, knots_ ):
    A = np.zeros((n_, n_))
    
    for i in range(n_):
        for j in range(n_):
            A[i, j] = cox_de_boor(d_, ts_[i], j, knots_)
    
    control_points = np.linalg.solve(A, P_)
    return control_points

def create_B_spline( d_, P_, t_, knots_):
    sum = MVector()
    for i in range( len(P_) ):
        sum += P_[i] * cox_de_boor(d_, t_, i, knots_)
    return sum
    
def B_spline( points_ ):
    d     = 3
    P     = np.array( points_ )
    n     = len( P )
    ts    = np.linspace( 0.0, 1.0, n )
    knots = knotvector.generate( d, n ) # len = n + d + 1
    
    control_points = interpolate( d, P, n, ts, knots)
    
    crv_pnts = []
    for i in range(10):
        t = float(i) / 9
        crv_pnts.append( create_B_spline(d, control_points, t, knots) )
    return crv_pnts


control_points = [ [float(i), math.sin(i), 0.0] for i in range(8) ]
cps = B_spline( control_points )

Result:


What are the values in that if when it fails?

see https://www.cs.montana.edu/courses/spring2009/525/dslectures/CoxdeBoor.pdf section 4

@jared: It's the knot values, I'll have to print them out, but because it's the last point they'll be both 1.0. So, 1.0 <= 1.0 <= 1.0. Therefore, in the < form, you'd get 1.0 <= 1.0 < 1.0, which is why it doesn't return 1.0. The question is why doesn't the code conform to the requirements of the mathematical equation.

@Stef: Thank you for the link. But this is not well referenced and very poor in context / explanation. I do not see any references of this text. Where is this coming from? Seems like a solution that happened to work and someone wrote it down on a pdf. Also, it says "The major advantage of the < form comes when we have a knot vector that includes two or more equal knots.". The knot vector I have for, ex. 4 points (num_of_points:4 + degree:3 + 1), is {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}. Therefore, the < form should have sufficed. Am I missing something?

The mathematical condition is the correct one, B-Spline basis functions are defined on a half-open interval.
However, it presents a problem when the knot vector is clamped, as you show in your example.
The problem is that in this case the mathematical function isn't defined at t=1,
and the result in the code is that it evaluates to 0 as you showed.
What you would like to have in this case, is for the function to be evaluated to 1 (which is the limit at t=1).
One way to achieve this is to apply your fix of using <= instead of <.
The figures below show a plot of the resulting basis function for n=5 (for which your default knot vector is
[0,0,0,0,0.5,1,1,1,1]) using your fix and using the original mathematical definition.
The functions were sampled at t = linspace(0,1,101).


As can be seen, both implementations result in similar basis functions in "almost all" values.
However, while the <= fix sets the value at t=1 to 1 as we wanted, it clearly
ruins the functions at the inner knot value t=0.5.
The original implementation, on the other hand, ruins the function at the end knot value t=1 as we already know,
but only there and only for the last function.
Basically, one can say that the basis functions implemented with the <=-fix are "almost-correct" except for inner-knot values.
Here is another example figure to demonstrate the phenomeneon for n=7.

So, now that we know what the problem is and what we want the result to be, one can think of different ways to fix it.
The following code is an example of such a fix, it wraps the recursive definition with a function that checks for
(d+1)-multiplicity knots and sets it to 1 (a clamped knot vector is the most common use-case of this).
def cox_de_boor(d_, t_, k_, knots_):
    # Handling end-parameter of clamped knot vector (and also the not-so-useful case of (d+1)-multiplicity inner knots)
    if t_ == knots_[k_ + 1] and t_ == knots_[k_ + d_ + 1]:
        return 1.0

    return cox_de_boor_recursive(d_, t_, k_, knots_)


def cox_de_boor_recursive(d_, t_, k_, knots_):
    if (d_ == 0):
        if (knots_[k_] <= t_ < knots_[k_ + 1]):
            return 1.0

        return 0.0

    denom_l = (knots_[k_ + d_] - knots_[k_])
    left = 0.0
    if (denom_l != 0.0):
        left = ((t_ - knots_[k_]) / denom_l) * cox_de_boor_recursive(d_ - 1, t_, k_, knots_)

    denom_r = (knots_[k_ + d_ + 1] - knots_[k_ + 1])
    right = 0.0
    if (denom_r != 0.0):
        right = ((knots_[k_ + d_ + 1] - t_) / denom_r) * cox_de_boor_recursive(d_ - 1, t_, k_ + 1, knots_)

    return left + right


And here is the result we get when using this function on the example from above.


nicely explained, and the illustration helped. thanks!
